# Is there a way of writing this loop more efficiently?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
i = 2
while (i != len(recipe)):
        print(recipe[i])
        i += 1
        print(recipe[i])
        i += 1
        print(recipe[i])
        i += 1
```

could this while loop be written any simplier , it looks a but messy

Comment: What if Len(recipe) is not exactly a multiple of 3 plus 2?

Comment: You will go out of bounds. Isn't this code crashing?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth will get out of bound even if multiple of 3.

Comment: Please show us recipe object with expected output - logic is ambiguous and we have no idea what are you trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
for item in recipe[2:]:
   print(item)
```

although the behaviour won't be exactly identical in the situations where your original code would have thrown an IndexError.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 2
length = len(recipe)
while(i != length):
    print(recipe[i])
    print(recipe[i+1])
    print(recipe[i+2])
    i += 3
```

or

```
i = 2
length = len(recipe)
while(i != length):
    print(recipe[i],recipe[i+1],recipe[i+2])
    i += 3
```

Obviously you will have to handle the IndexError

Comment: Your second example needs `sep='\n'`

Comment: print(str(recipe[i])+"\n"+str(recipe[i+1])+'\n'+str(recipe[i+2]))